# Pergunta que pede lista de coisas interessantes sobre jQuery

Tags: debate, comunidade, pergunta-específica

Apareceu uma PERGUNTA DE LISTA `</provocacao>` bem diferente da [lista de livros para iniciantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugues-para-iniciantes-absolutos-em-programacao): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6010/coisas-interessantes-sobre-o-jquery-que-as-pessoas-nao-sabem

"Coisas interessantes" é subjetivo, o que eu acho interessante outros não vão achar. "As pessoas" ou "a maioria dos usuários" é um grupo vago, mas que certamente existe – sempre haverá *alguém* que achará *algo* interessante.

A resposta mais completa possível para ela seria a documentação do jQuery traduzida para o português, acompanhada de um índice de destaques comentados. É um conteúdo que não existe em português. Seria bom se existisse, mas o objetivo do site é ser um repositório de documentação traduzida? E quanto trabalho daria traduzir (e manter) a documentação do jQuery? Então parece um caminho pouco plausível.

O que é plausível é que surjam várias respostas, e que elas se sobreponham em parte. Tem gente que vai achar uma ou outra interessante, e algumas se tornarão mais populares com o tempo. Sempre haverá coisas que as pessoas acharão interessantes, sempre faltarão coisas que as pessoas achariam interessantes, e sempre haverá coisas que as pessoas acharão desinteressantes. Não existe uma resposta que se possa objetivamente considerar "correta".

Então a pergunta não é boa para o formato *pergunta e resposta*. Também não parece boa para o formato de wiki (neste caso, wiki comunitário, ou wiki da tag jQuery). Parece mais adequada como um post de um blog. Mas essa pergunta tem um público. Ela gera visitas e pode atrair novos usuários para o site. Existem pessoas que vão achar ali conteúdos que considerão interessantes.

No momento desta postagem, a pergunta está suspensa, com alguns votos contra, e vem com este aviso embaixo:

> Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.
>   Se essa pergunta pode ser reformulada para se adequar às regras na central de ajuda, edite a pergunta ou deixe um comentário.

O aviso sinaliza aos usuários que a pergunta tem problemas em relação ao formato *pergunta e resposta*, que a comunidade espera que seja o formato deste site. Ele indica que perguntas semelhantes provavelmente serão suspensas também. Isso causa efeitos diferentes em grupos diferentes de pessoas:

- Um grupo de usuários achará o aviso antipático ou injusto, pois desejava encontrar esse tipo de conteúdo no site. Uma parte dessas pessoas nunca mais volta ao site, e outra parte volta mesmo assim – talvez com uma impressão ruim da comunidade daqui, talvez não.
- Outro grupo de usuários considera a pergunta subjetiva demais para o formato do site, e acredita que seja bom sinalizar o tipo de pergunta que é mais adequado à ferramenta.
- Um outro grupo nem liga para a pergunta, para a mensagem de suspensão, para o futuro do site, ou para qualquer outra questão envolvida.
- Deve ter gente que acha este debate sem propósito, fora de hora ou fora de lugar.
- E ainda deve haver mais grupos com opiniões diferentes.

O que eu pergunto à comunidade é:

- **O que você acha dessa pergunta específica?**
- **Alguma sugestão de como editar a pergunta?**
- **O que perguntas similares podem ou devem representar para o futuro do site?**

Minha opinião está implícita no meu voto para fechar. Posso desenvolvê-la mais adiante se for o caso, neste momento estou interessado nas opiniões da comunidade e da Stack Exchange.

Comment: `(...)pois desejava encontrar esse tipo de conteúdo no site` Desejar por desejar, podem desejar o que quiserem. Esse tipo de conteúdo é adequado para fóruns e para o **Yahoo! Respostas**, não para os sites do *Stack Exchange*.

Comment: Se alguém cria uma resposta em torno de um livro (como é comum em perguntas de lista), posso/devo sinalizar a resposta como spam? Porque pra mim essas respostas não são nada além disso.

Comment: Não @Renan, o sinalizador de spam é para quando alguém usa o site para divulgar algum serviço ou produto, muitas vezes nem relacionado à pergunta (no caso de spam postado como resposta). Não abuse desse sinalizador, quem tem respostas excluídas como spam sofre punições bastante severas.

Comment: Ok, eu não sabia disso. Vou me limitar aos votos negativos nesses casos.

Answer (score 8):

## Opinião pessoal

> O que você acha dessa pergunta específica?

Essa pergunta e outras do mesmo "tipo" são claramente perguntas que **NUNCA** vão ter uma resposta acertada ou a terem uma marcada como tal, **NUNCA** vai existir um consenso por parte de toda a comunidade de que é efetivamente a resposta acertada.

[image: Contra as listas]
<sup>Imagem criada com recursos do http://www.sxc.hu/.</sup>

> Alguma sugestão de como editar a pergunta?

Na sua forma atual, a pergunta procura opiniões sobre os mais variados assuntos através da recolha de experiências pessoais de cada um no decorrer da utilização e aprendizagem de jQuery.

Não vejo como transformar isto numa pergunta útil e válida agora e no futuro para todos os utilizadores.

> O que perguntas similares podem ou devem representar para o futuro do site?

Isto é quase que outra discussão, mas numa forma geral, este tipo de perguntas não encaixa minimamente num site de *Perguntas&Respostas* onde a pergunta deve apresentar um problema claro e especifico a ser resolvido, de forma a que as respostas dadas possam todas ir de encontro com o mesmo objetivo, dando assim a hipótese do tópico ser fechado através da marcação de uma das respostas como correta sabendo que a mesma resolveu o problema apresentado na pergunta.

---

## Central de ajuda

Não quero deixar de referir que a nossa central de ajuda já se encontra traduzida e no texto onde podemos ler os assuntos a ***não perguntar***, conseguimos apurar que a pergunta em questão se encaixa perfeitamente em dois deles:

> - toda resposta seja igualmente válida: “Qual é seu _ favorito?”
> - não haja um problema real para resolver: “Tenho curiosidade de saber se outras pessoas se sentem como eu.”

Observando a secção da nossa central de ajuda que cobre o tipo de perguntas a evitar, pode-se ler:

#### [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

> **Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada [e possivelmente removida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions), evite fazer perguntas subjetivas onde …**
>
> - toda resposta seja igualmente válida: “Qual é seu _ favorito?”
> - sua resposta seja fornecida junto com a pergunta e você espera mais respostas: “Eu uso _ para _, o que você usa?”
> - não haja um problema real para resolver: “Tenho curiosidade de saber se outras pessoas se sentem como eu.”
> - você faça uma pergunta hipotética e aberta: “E se acontecer _?”
> - sua pergunta seja apenas uma fanfarrice disfarçada: “__ é péssimo, concordam comigo?”

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a questão pode ser melhorada... pedindo algo de opinião pessoal, mas baseada em experiências... algo do tipo:

> Qual foi a sua descoberta sobre o jQuery que mais impactou no seu trabalho?

Ai então a reposta viria como algo do tipo:

> Na minha experiência com o jQuery, o que mais me fez feliz foi o dia que descobri que podia  > fazer delegação de eventos de um filho para o pai, pois dessa forma é possível que eu
>   carregue elementos via ajax dentro do pai, sem ter que dar bind nos eventos novamente.

Ai vem um monte de gente, vota, e ai pelo menos saberemos qual das experiências é a que as pessoas mais tiram proveito... ou seja, cada resposta vai ter um resuminho da biblioteca, e o resuminho mais útil vai ficar em cima de tudo com mais votos.

Comment: Isso ainda é questão de opinião, e não esclarece nem resolve nenhum problema real em si. Pior, transforma uma única pergunta em uma colação de várias soluções em busca de um problema.

Comment: @Renan Não vejo problema em dar opiniões que são fundamentadas em fatos. Isso é troca de experiência, e certamente muitos podem se beneficiar... assim como muitos já se beneficiam de questões assim no SO em inglês.